# Maui опубликованное apk не устанавливается на самом телефоне

Tags: c#, maui

Maui -> опубликованное apk не устанавливается на самом устройстве

По этому гайду получил apk файл

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-ad-hoc?view=net-maui-7.0

При дебаге в эмуляторе (android 9) приложение работает.

Но на реальном устройстве (android 9) этот apk не устанавливается(

Что упускаю ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании apk был ещё такой шаг...
Я заполнил рандомно - не понимая для чего это)

- Может дело в этом ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отладкой занимайтесь, получайте с устройства ошибку, и смотрите что ему не нравится. Для отладки поищите `android logcat`, думаю разберетесь. Просто "не устанавливается" - это ооооочень обширная проблема, которая может вылезти из кучи всего, например, вот [не так указана архитектура](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67223239/6808809).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо!  Буду разбираться

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не удаётся найти настроки как в том посте. Попробовал ещё сменить язык на eng и поском воспользоваться, но тоже нет. Где эти настройки запрятаны ?

Comment: Без понятия, я не MAUI разработчик, для меня он еще ооочень сырой) Я вам лишь даю подсказки, а изучайте их уж давайте самостоятельно. Вот я например начал с логов, это самое первое, что должен делать разработчик, а уже на их основе решал проблему.

Comment: @Xzizz Я уверен, что вы уже разобрались с этой проблемой. Но действительно стоит заполнить хранилище ключей для APK файла и сохранить его. Благодаря этому у меня получилось сегодня решить такую же проблему